# Why do I need "new" for jagged array initialization?

Tags: c#, arrays, jagged-arrays

In the past I've initialized arrays using the full initialization syntax:

```
int[] arr = new int[1] { 1 };
```

but once I found out I didn't need to specify the type during initialization I stopped doing that:

```
int[] arr = { 1 };
```

I looked into jagged arrays again recently and found a very peculiar issue with this syntax:

```
int[][] jag = { { 1, 2 }, { 3 } };
```

The above code is NOT valid, which puzzles me. Furthermore, this syntax IS fine:

```
int[][] jag = { new []{ 1, 2 }, new []{ 3 } };
```

Clearly the only difference here is the "new" keyword. Normally, in other languages, the "new" keyword signifies that the variable is going to be a reference type, but in C# arrays are always reference types, so there really is no need to specify "new" for arrays. Does anyone know why I need to specify it here in this jagged array initialization? Is this a bug, or maybe just an unimplemented compiler feature?

Comment: *but in C# arrays are always reference types, so there really is no need to specify "new" for arrays* That does not follow. It's not a bug, it's just not a bit of compiler sugar they built into the language. It may or may not be added in future. You can try to request it over at GitHub, but since jagged arrays are (in my experience) fricken rare, I'd doubt much action...

Comment: "new" does NOT signify that a type is a reference type. Since that is false, any conclusions that you've based on this false premise don't follow logically.  `int x = new int();` is a perfectly legal, albeit weird, way to write `int x = 0;`.  What `new` indicates is that *new storage is being allocated*. In the case of a value type, that storage is allocated off the temporary pool and then copied, in the case of a reference type, that storage is allocated off of the long term pool.

Comment: Another reason is that the nested-braces syntax `{ { ... }, { ... }, ... }` is syntactic-sugar for calling `.Add` for `IList` types. `System.Array` doesn't have `Add` - as well as for "native" multidimensional arrays: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/multidimensional-arrays

Comment: Note that the C# compiler and jitter are permitted to *copy-elide* if they can prove that doing so is safe.  For example, if you have `S s = new S(123);` for a value type `S`, the requirement of the spec is that new storage is allocated, the new storage is passed to the constructor, the constructor runs, and then the value type is copied by value to `s`.  **Exercise: under what circumstances could the compiler legally pass the storage of `s` to the constructor and skip the alloc-and-copy? Under what circumstances could it not?**

Comment: I prefaced that sentence with "normally" because in "normal" usage of the keyword new, it pretty much always is for reference types. As you pointed out yourself, <code>int x = new int();</code> isn't "normal", it's weird. More importantly, I was also referencing C/C++ which returns a pointer when you use new.

Comment: C does not have `new`.  Though `new int()` is weird, `new Point(1, 2)` is perfectly normal for a value type `Point`. Use a backtick to delineate a code block in a comment, not `<code>`.

Comment: That feel when @EricLippert smacks you down :(

Comment: @Will: There's no smack down intended. I'm just making statements of fact. There's a bias in all-text communications that makes statements of fact sound like criticisms, but they're just facts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is this a bug?

Nope.

> Does anyone know why I need to specify it here in this jagged array initialization?

There is no fundamental theoretical reason why the C# language must allow the array initializer syntax only for rectangular multidimensional arrays and not for jagged multidimensional arrays.

The feature you want does not exist because no one ever designed, specified, implemented, tested, documented and shipped that feature.  That's because the feature could reasonably be characterized as very, very unimportant compared to pretty much any other possible feature you could spend time on. Features are expensive; the design team tries to spend time on features that solve real user problems.

Little "sugar" features like the one you propose do get implemented; expression-bodied methods, for example. But *almost every program contains small methods*. The vast majority of programs do not contain even one jagged, initialized-once array, so this feature would be work that saves almost no one half a dozen keystrokes. Not worth it.

> maybe just an unimplemented compiler feature that will be fixed in a future version of C#?

If this feature is important to you, well, the design and implementation process is open. Feel free to propose, design, specify, implement, test and document the feature, and see if they accept your pull request.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for, thanks. It seems I may have offended some, considering the harsh nature of the comments above; sorry about that. My wording could have been better - I could care less about this bit of syntactic sugar, I was just curious why it didn't exist. I suspected this might be the reason.

Comment: @Darkhydro: No offense was taken or intended. There is a bias in all-text communication which makes statements of fact sound like criticisms, when they're simply statements of fact.